# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset on JMeter

Tags: jmeter

i am trying to automate the web process and that website only access when i am using VPN so when i try to Record the Website Script using the JMeter Script recoder then i shows error " You connection is not Private for this site " and when i am trying to run the JMeter as a Proxy server by using this command jMeter.bat -H -P -N -u -a then i am getting " java.net.SocketException: Connection reset " Error. So if anyone know how to recode the VPN accessed web application test script in JMeter please help me.
Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1):

"You connection is not Private for this site" error means that you haven't imported JMeter's certificate into your browser.

When you start JMeter [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) it generates a special certificate file called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation, the certificate allows JMeter to intercept and decrypt [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) traffic so make sure to import the certificate into your browser before opening the page of the application you're testing.

More information:

- **HTTPS recording and certificates** of [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) user manual entry
- [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server)

if you're still seeing the error - try clearing your browsing history as it might be the case your browser "remembers" valid certificate for the page you're trying to open and detects certificate mismatch when you're opening it via JMeter's proxy.

With regards to VPN I don't think any extra steps are required once you're able to open the application with browser and/or JMeter

Comment: Thanks for the Reply but i already add the ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt certificate in Browser but still when i provide the login credential it shows error " Your connection is not private for this site " and at that time i am still connected by VPN

Comment: I find the error and error was when link hit on browser it share VPN server IP address and port no but when we configure the JMeter Proxy we set the IP to localhost and Port to 8181 so that's why browser send Error Message